# how to handle broken XML Microsoft Office Word documents

Tags: windows, xml, libreoffice, file-format

I have received an `xml` file with a form that I am supposed to fill. The filename ends in `.doc`, so I assume it's supposed to be a word document. As far as I understand it was automatically generated by an online system and then sent to me - in case you are wondering, it's some legal form to be filled by foreigners intending to live and/or work in France.

However, I think that the online system did not correctly generate the file, and I'm thinking about how to rescue it. Unfortunately, I don't have a version of Microsoft Office available, since I'm working on Linux - and libreoffice doesn't seem to recognize the file format and simply displays the `xml` code as any usual editor would.

What do I need to do to this `xml` file to make it readable and editable by libreoffice in the same way it was intended to be used in Microsoft Office?

Here's a [link](https://pastebin.com/SZt8PmtF) to the first few lines of the form - I suppose this is needed in order to judge what file format this is even supposed to be (`doc`, `docx`, ..., ?)

Comment: Does LibreOffice handle the file properly if it has the extension `.docx`?

Comment: Zipping and renaming to ´docx´ or just renaming to ´docx´ does nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have this one file. After experimenting for a little bit, I found that it is probably intended to be an RTF document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was an RTF document, and I was able to open it with libreoffice after changing the file extension.